# Change or parse CRM FetchXML with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, regex, linq

I have a CRM FetchXML string. This has a linked entity which means the XML Elements are prefixed with a GUID, such as:

```
 <a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.lastname>Bob</a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.lastname>
 <a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.firstname>Bob</a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.firstname> 
 <a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.title name="Mr" formattedvalue="1">1</a_6dd7d25cb0be4150bbaec7c0d2f430c7.title>
```

I would like to use it in a way similar to this:

```
List<FetchResult> results =
            (from result in xmlDoc.Descendants("result")
             select new FetchResult
             {
                 FirstName = result.Element("firstname").Value
             }).ToList<FetchResult>();
```

Obviously this won't work, so is there anyway I can do a `Element.Contains("lastname")` or similar?
If not, is there way I can parse this out of my string before hand? Perhaps regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<FetchResult> results =
            (from result in xmlDoc.Descendants("result")
             select new FetchResult
             {
                 FirstName = result.Elements().First(el => el.EndsWith("firstname")).Value
             }).ToList<FetchResult>();
```

Should work

Comment: +1 Thanks for this - it didn't quite work, but pushed me in the right direction. I'll add correct syntax now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Foo42` - this is the updated syntax

```
FirstName = result.Elements().First(el => el.Name.ToString().EndsWith("firstname")).Value
```

Comment: Oh yeah, Elements is a method isn't it!